# How to access ActiveX Checkbox in Excel 2007 using OpenXML

Tags: activex, excel-2007, openxml

I have found many pages where it has been explained how to get Checkboxes in Word 2007. But could anyone explain how to fetch/access the ActiveX checkboxes in Excel 2007 using OpenXML? I tried generating the code for such an Excel file using the OpenXML sdk Tool and found out that the Checkbox is of a "Control()" type. But while reading the sheet in C# using OpenXml i am unable to access it.
Thanks.